# Xamarin does not recognize the installed fonts

Tags: ios, fonts, xamarin.ios, xamarin, controls

I am trying to start building an app for ios using Xamarin and I have a localization problem.

I have installed some custom fonts in my mac which the Notes application recognizes and has no problem with.

But the font don't appear in Properties panel of the controls in Xamarin.

Thanks before.

Comment: You should show some code. It is hard to tell what you are trying to achieve. Here's an example how to use custom fonts in a Xamarin.iOS app: http://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/

Comment: I'm not changing fonts in the code. I just drag and drop Views in storyboard and try to change the font in the Properties panel of the view. There are a couple of fonts in there in Font section, but none of the fonts I have installed in my Mac.

Comment: Bear in mind you should not see fonts installed on your mac. The only relevant fonts are either the ones available in iOS (which are displayed by default) or custom fonts added to your application (which are displayed in Xamarin Studio 5.7+).

Answer (score 2):

Alan solves the question.

A solution to do it in code:

**Xamarin iOS**:

```
(ILabel).Font = UIFont.FromName ("font name", 30f);
```

Your font needs to be built like a "Content" in any directory

**Xamarin Android**:

```
(TextView).SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, DISPLAY_FONT), TypefaceStyle.Normal);

(TextView).TextSize = 32;
```

Needs to be copied to your `/Assets/(FONT).TTF` and needs to be built like `AndroidAsset`

;-)

Answer (score 1):

Custom fonts should show up in the property panel in Xamarin Studio 5.7 and higher.

Comment: I added the fonts in Xamarin too, as well as the Mac.Following this link :http://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/ But still it does not appear in the View's property.